# Вычислить возраст в годах python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Необходимо вычислить возраст для списка клиентов, но мой вариант ругается:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
    if df['Дата продажи'] is not None and df['Дата рождения'] is not None:
        df['Возраст'] = relativedelta(df['Дата продажи'], df['Дата рождения']).years else:
        df['Возраст'] = 10000
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

Посоветуйте вариант решения?

Comment: Покажите содержимое `df`

Comment: df['Дата продажи'] и df['Дата рождения'] -  datetime или пустота, в df большое количество данных

Comment: А ошибка точно в приведённых строках? В тексте встречается имя `Series`, которого нет в представленном коде.

Comment: Вариант решения - считать не для все колонки, а брать кажду строчку по отдельности. Если в одной строке есть дата рождения, а в другой нет, то что выдаст ``df['Дата рождения'] is not None``? Именно об этом написано в ошибке.

Comment: @Эникейщик Как считать для каждой строчки? Цикл? Я с sql работал только, там с этим проще

Comment: Ну да, цикл. Хотя, может быть, есть какая-нибудь функция которая сама циклом считает. Я с этими модулями плохо знаком.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) для построчных операций. Пример: парсим `DataFrame` из текста, для обоих столбцов (`dob` и `buy`) конвертируем данные из текста в дату:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


raw = '''dob  buy
18.03.1971    01.01.2019
08.12.1952    31.03.2018
09.01.1999    30.10.2010
16.08.1992    05.05.2019
13.03.1987    09.09.2018
None          None
None          01.01.2019
01.01.2019    None'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(raw), sep='\s{2,}')
df['buy'] = pd.to_datetime(df['buy'], format='%d.%m.%Y', errors='coerce')
df['dob'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dob'], format='%d.%m.%Y', errors='coerce')
```

Теперь создаем новый столбец `age`, содержащий разницу между `buy` и `dob`:

```
def age(row):
    dob = row['dob']
    buy = row['buy']
    if pd.isnull(dob) or pd.isnull(buy):
        return 10000
    return relativedelta(buy, dob).years

df['age'] = df.apply(age, axis=1)
```

Новый датафрейм:

```
         dob        buy    age
0 1971-03-18 2019-01-01     47
1 1952-12-08 2018-03-31     65
2 1999-01-09 2010-10-30     11
3 1992-08-16 2019-05-05     26
4 1987-03-13 2018-09-09     31
5        NaT        NaT  10000
6        NaT 2019-01-01  10000
7 2019-01-01        NaT  10000
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Получилось. Подскажете ресурс где лучше учить питон?

Comment: Рад был помочь! Для питона не посоветую, но для `pandas` есть отличная книга от автора библиотеки: Wes McKinney, Python for Data Analysis, рекомендую.